# .htaccess file not working on linux server

Tags: html, .htaccess, configuration, server

I know there are more questions and answers about that but none of them was usefull to me.

I just configured my website on a apache linux server,that I'm managing with cPannel.And I edited my `.htaccess` file to remove html extensions from my url. But after I uploaded it to File manager , nothing changes.What do I need to do to make it work ?

I've been searching for configuration files to set `AllowOverride All` but I didn't found anything.And also I don't have `etc/apache2/` directory in my file manager, there are other files in `etc/` directory.

EDIT: Server info :

Hosting Package:Startup2013

Server Name:    wolf

cPanel Version: 11.50.1 (build 3)

Theme:  paper_lantern

Apache Version: 2.4.16

PHP Version:    5.6.12

MySQL Version:  5.6.23

Architecture:   x86_64

Operating System:   linux

Shared IP Address:  185.81.0.40

Path to Sendmail:   /usr/sbin/sendmail

Path to Perl:   /usr/bin/perl

Perl Version:   5.10.1

Kernel Version: 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64

Here is my `.htaccess` code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're not running an ubuntu server, that's why you don't have `/etc/apache2` directory.

Try this:

Edit the `httpd.conf` file in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and set the `AllowOverride All`

then: `apachectl restart`

If this doesn't work please run: `cat /etc/*-release` and show us the output, so we can know which linux distribution you are running.

**EDIT:** .htaccess was working fine, OP wanted to remove .html extensions

This is the .htaccess you need in order to remove .html extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.html\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I also don't have that directory, in my `etc/` I have another folder named `mywebsite.com` and some files called `ftpquota` and `cacheid` . I also searched for any `.conf` file and I found just 2 files called `/.cpanel/caches/config/_etc_sysconfig_authconfig___default
` and `/.gnupg/gpg.conf`

Comment: I just edited my answer, run the command: cat /etc/*-release   and tell us which linux distribution you are using.

Comment: I see the problem is that you are via ftp or a web  file viewer. Try logging to the server via ssh: ssh user@hostname

Comment: My website is hosted by a host company . I found some informations abut the server . Apache Version:2.4.16 and is runing on Linux OS

Comment: Add the server info to your question, so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: What's the name of the hosting company?

Comment: The name of the company is "Serverplan" . Link to them : http://www.serverplan.com/en/shared-hosting/

Comment: When you mean it isn't working, what it's actually happening, is there any error? Try adding some errors to the .htaccess  and tell me if there is an internal server error. Add some random text at the end.

Comment: I added some random text, and now when I acces the website it gives me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Well then it's something wrong in my code ?  Because doesnt hide `.html` extensions :|

Comment: The code doesn't hide the .html extensions, what the code does, you enter: mysite.com/test  and serves test.html file.

Comment: Depending what you want to do.. the code is working, and is doing what you tell it to do :P, I'm just happy to help you.

Comment: I want to hide `.html` extensions , i took the code from a article :\ Anyway you helped me so thank you !

Comment: Let's help you with that then! But you need some changes in that .htaccess

Comment: Sure !  What changes I need ?

Comment: It gives me 404 error, seems like it didnt found the file www.mysite.com/index/

Comment: which url are you trying to access? I made several tests with that .htaccess in my local server and eveything went perfectly.